# Writing an http server in c with connection persistence support

Tags: c, http, server, connection, keep-alive

When I read a request from a browser, the **HTTP** connection header always comes with a `Keep-Alive` value, so I kept the connection socket descriptor open after writing a response to the stream. I heard that this causes the client (browser) will reuse the same connection to send the next request.

But the client sends another `connect()` request to create a new connection for sending the next request.

Why do browsers send `keep-alive` option with every header?

Comment: Make sure all your responses either have `Content-Length:` or use chunked encoding, so that the client can tell when the response is done without waiting for you to close the connection.

Comment: Clients may open multiple connections so they can download multiple items concurrently. For instance, while it's downloading the main HTML page, if it sees an `<img>` it will open another connection to download that at the same time, rather than waiting until it has download all the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the client sends another connect() request to create a new connection for sending the next request.

If you are sending an HTTP 1.0 response to an HTTP 1.0/1.1 request:

- the default behavior is `Connection: close` unless a `Connection: keep-alive` response header is sent (**only** if the client sends a `Connection: keep-alive` request header!).  If you do not send that, the client will have no choice but to close the connection and make a new one each time.

If you are sending an HTTP 1.1 response to an HTTP 1.1 request:

- the default behavior is `Connection: keep-alive` unless a `Connection: close` response header is sent, so make sure you are not sending that unless the client sends a `Connection: close` request header, or you are intentionally closing the connection.

Either way, if the connection is going to be kept alive after the response has been sent, consider also including a separate [`Keep-Alive`](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-thomson-hybi-http-timeout-01.html) response header to inform compatible clients of when the connection will timeout and be closed if the client does not re-use it before the timeout elapses (and then be sure to actually implement that timeout in your server code).  For example:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=300
```

> why do browsers send keep-alive option with every header?

Because it is a per-request feature.  Any request can ask to keep the connection alive, and the server has to acknowledge it each time. Once a connection has been closed, it is gone.